# How to get data type of any object's field in SOQL

Tags: soql, metadata-api, dynamic-soql, database

how to i get datatype of any filed in SOQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can get the all the standard and custom objects fields data types using the `getGlobalDescribe`, `getDescribe`, `getType`.

```
String objType=’Account’;
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objType);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {

    //get all the fields label for Account Object
    String fieldLabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();

    //get data types for each fields
    Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.TextArea) {
        /* build your logic if the Field data type is TextArea */
    }

    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.String) {
        /* build your logic if the Field data type is String */
    }

    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.Integer) {
        /* build your logic if the Field data type is Integer */
    }

    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.DateTime) {
        /* build your logic if the Field data type is DateTime */
    }

}
```

Here `Schema.DisplayType` enum value is returned by the field describe result’s getType method.

**Click here for more details:**

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_

Comment: It should be `==` instead of `!=`

Comment: ohhh yaa thanx!!! will update